# is there a way to write coalesce query to remove null from a file and use in scala code with a filter after extracting from a file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let us suppose I have a file on Hadoop on which external table is made:

```
criteria-column name
value-column1<>column2
```

But `column2` contains some NULL values, so it is not being filtered and those values are skipped.

Is there a way I write a coalesce statement in a file in column criteria and that can work with a filter? There is a way that I can do it in code, before filtering like below:

```
withColumn("column2",coalesce(col("column2"),lit(0)))
```

But I need to get the statement from a file so that it can be used with a filter, and I don't want to change the code. Is there a way?

Comment: `df.filter(expr("column1 <> coalesce(column2, 0)"))` ? or `df.filter(expr("column1 <> ifnull(column2, 0)"))`...

Comment: please explain the issue better. I am confused if you want to filter null or what else? You don't need coalesce for filtering null.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can filter based on NULL value on a column -

```
val df = // dataframe containing 2 columns column1, column2. Column2 contains null

df.filter($"column2".isNull).map(// act on the rows where column2 is null)
```